# getting a line which has the highest date for each id sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table

```
PKID : int - primary key
Date : datetime
ID_2 : int
lots of other columns..
...
...
```

How do I get the line with the highest **Date** for each unique **ID_2** ?

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT PKID, 
       Date, 
       ID_2, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_2 ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RN
FROM your_table
)
SELECT PKID, 
       Date, 
       ID_2
FROM cte 
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;with t as
(
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_2 order by date desc) rn,tableName.*
    from
        tableName
)
select * from t where rn=1
```

I'm lazy and used *. You shouldn't

Comment: You seem to be missing a `FROM` in your CTE definition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `MAX()` and `GROUP`;

```
SELECT 
  ID_2,
  MAX([Date]) AS TheDate
FROM tbl 
  GROUP BY ID_2
```

Comment: The OP wants the "line" by which I assume they mean "whole row".

Comment: thank you for answering!
the problem is that I want to select the whole line ( other columns.. ) 
then I get the message: 

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'ID_NODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.